# How to find cyclic subgroups of $S_4$ with certain numbers of elements

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics, cyclic-groups, binary-operations

In the group $S_n$ consisting of the set of all bijections from $\{1,2,...,n\}$ to $\{1,2,...,n\}$ with a binary operation $◦$ denoting composition of functions. I am asked to find cyclic subgroups of $S_4$ with 2,3, and 4 elements. For a cyclic subgroup with 2 elements I have $\{(1,3),(2,4),(3,1),(4,2)\}$, but am looking for help in finding cyclic subgroups of larger sizes.

Comment: Your notation is very puzzling. (i) A subgroup has to contain the identity element, and I don't see it in the strange set you write down. (ii) As you want a subgroup of order 2 there's got to be one other element, of order 2. Did you intend the map that swaps 1 and 3, and swaps 2 and 4? If so we'd usually write it $\begin{pmatrix} 1& 2 & 3& 4\\3 &  4 & 1 & 2\end{pmatrix}$ or just $(13)(24)$.

Comment: did you mean to say that each of the transpositions when considered separately along with the identity form a cyclic sub-group of size two?

Comment: You may need to improve your notation, which is confusing. Also to specify a subgroup you need to identify all the elements.

Comment: Consider composing cycles of different sizes with themselves. For example, compose $(1\,2\,3)$ with itself and $(1\,2\,3\,4)$ with itself to see what cyclic sub-groups those elements generate

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3428860/list-the-cyclic-subgroups-of-s4?noredirect=1&lq=1) for the answer. There are $17$ cyclic subgroups of $S_4$. See the [homework solution](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiYs92P6OTwAhVlpYsKHdzcBNwQFjAOegQIFRAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmath.dartmouth.edu%2F~auel%2Fcourses%2F370f06%2Fdocs%2Fsolutions5.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0ZhaFVUDZzHEHq64pLXOM2).